# Event "formSubmission" doesn't trigger on Circuit SDK

Tags: circuit-sdk

Circuit client in my app subscribed to event 'formSubmission':

```
client.addEventListener('formSubmission', function (event)
```

Until last days it works fine, but now it doesn't trigger.

I tried to test it by creating a simple app that just send a form (just one button on it) as a reply to user's message and should log form submissions, but it doesn't go on this function.

```
client.addEventListener('formSubmission', function (event) {
     var submittedValue = event.form.data[0].value;
     console.log(`[CIRCUIT]: Form was submitted.`);
};
```

Any other events like 'itemAdded' or 'itemUpdated' work as they should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just confirmed this is a bug and is being worked on. Will post here when its resolved. Are you using the circuitsandbox.net or production?

Comment: For testing I used circuitsandbox. But I use production as well

Answer (score 1):

Production systems have been updated and the formSubmission event is received again. circuitsandbox will be updated with this fix soon.